# Form options values having php code within them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html-select

How can I add PHP code to a form option value. The PHP code is actually part of a Wordpress plugin that serves a certain function. When you click on a certain value, I want an option to show up (using the PHP code).

```
<option value="<?php 
    echo wpws_get_content('http://eoddata.com/stockquote/NASDAQ/GOOG.htm',
                          '#ctl00_cph1_cc1_ct1' ); 
?>">Chart</option>
```

Comment: No you can't. PHP runs BEFORE the dropdown is even shown on the screen. So it downloads that stock thing BEFORE it even displays the dropdown and all its options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the whole form out using PHP. This makes sure that the PHP has loaded first before it changes the value.